# How to join multiple columns from different tables

Tags: oracle

How can you join multiple tables and display values from tables that referenced further in other tables?

```
select booking.booking_id,
(select customer.first_name from customer
where customer.customer_id=booking.customer_id) as First_Name,
(select customer.last_name from customer
where customer.customer_id=booking.customer_id) as Last_Name,
(select aircraft_model.aircraft_model from aircraft_model
where aircraft_model_id = (select aircraft.aircraft_model_id from 
aircraft
where aircraft_modle_id = booking.aircraft_id))

from booking;
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass on the value of `aircraft_model_id` from the table `booking` to the `aircraft_model` table.

The only table connecting the `aircraft_model` table to the `booking` table is the `aircraft` table..

I'm completely new to sql so please do state if there are any errors.

Added in the codes for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (
Booking_ID            NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Company_ID            NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Penrhyn_Jet_Charter(Company_ID),
Customer_ID           NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Customer(Customer_ID),
Aircraft_ID           NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Aircraft(Aircraft_ID),
Assignment_No         NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
Booking_Date          DATE         DEFAULT SYSDATE,
Charter_Cost          NUMBER(14,2) CHECK(Charter_Cost > 0),
Departure_Date        DATE         NOT NULL,
Departure_Location    CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
Arrival_Date          DATE         NOT NULL,
Arrival_Destination   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Aircraft_Model (
Aircraft_Model_ID     NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Aircraft_Model        VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
No_Of_Aircrafts       NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL CHECK (No_Of_Aircrafts > 
0),
Aircraft_Description  VARCHAR2(500) 
);

CREATE TABLE Aircraft (
Aircraft_ID       NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Company_ID        NUMBER(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Penrhyn_jet_Charter(Company_ID),
Aircraft_Model_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Aircraft_Model(Aircraft_Model_ID),
Seats             NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, use `INNER JOIN` from `booking` to `aircraft_model`

```
SELECT
    b.booking_id,
    c.firstname AS First_Name,
    c.last_name AS Last_Name,
    am.aircraft_model
FROM booking b
INNER JOIN customer c ON b.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN aircraft a ON b.aircraft_id = a.aircraft_model_id
INNER JOIN aircraft_model am ON a.aircraft_model_id = am.aircraft_model_id
```

Comment: It works, but the values in the column aren't displayed, is that because of a lack of WHERE clause?

Comment: is the customer id exists both in booking and customer tables? is aircraft_id exists in both customer and aircraft tables? because I used INNER JOIN here. If not existing, you might want to try OUTER JOINS instead.

Comment: Customer id exists in both booking and customer tables, however aircraft_id only exists in booking and aircraft table. Aircraft_Model_ID exists in aircraft table and Aircraft_Model table. the column - aircraft_model only exists in Aircraft_Model table.

Comment: I have added in the code for the tables to the question.

Comment: I mean the data itself. If there is a data for example, aircraft_model data which is existing in aircraft  but not existing customer (or no relation), INNER JOIN will not work. Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. Play with the JOINS to get the desired results.

Comment: Yes all the tables are populated, I figured out a solution! I will add it to the bottom of this post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The query below works to display the desired output for the question stated above.

```
SELECT
booking.booking_id,
customer.first_name,
customer.last_name,
aircraft.aircraft_id,
aircraft_model.aircraft_model
FROM
booking
INNER JOIN customer ON customer.customer_id = booking.customer_id
INNER JOIN aircraft ON aircraft.aircraft_id = booking.aircraft_id
INNER JOIN aircraft_model ON aircraft_model.aircraft_model_id = 
aircraft.aircraft_model_id;
```

Comment: Your join on aircraft_model does not look correct as you are using the primary key of the aircraft table to join to the primary key of the aircraft_model table which means the data is not likely matching up unless there is only 1 of each model aircraft and they where inserted into both tables with the same primary key.

Comment: I just realised that, is there a way to make it work then?

Comment: The final join should be a. aircraft_model_id = am. aircraft_model_id since the aircraft model join is in the two aircraft tables.

Comment: Updated the answer, that has solved the problem of not all bookings being shown!